# make openvpn server use other external IP set on interface as an alias

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I have openvpn **server** installed on server.

My external network interface is : **eth0**.

**eth0** have external\real IP addr like **33.33.33.33**

I also have **eth0:1** interface alias wich have ip addr like **44.44.44.44**

What I should to to make openvpn use SOURCE ADDRESS **44.44.44.44** and not the **33.33.33.33** ?

my default route looks like:

```
0.0.0.0         33.33.33.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

is there some openvpn option for server to bind some interface and use it's ip wich works ok with IP assigned as an alias ?

Comment: You really should get rid of alias interfaces if at all possible. Linux natively supports multiple IP addresses per interface. // What exactly do you mean by “source address”? Do you perhaps mean that VPN clients should appear as `44.44.44.44` on the external network?

Answer (score 0):

The primary operation is actually binding to an address, not to an interface. (That exists but is a secondary thing that's much less commonly used.) So you can forget interfaces and directly tell OpenVPN to bind to your preferred address using the 'local' option:

```
local 44.44.44.44
```

---

Also note that "interface aliases" on Linux **are not** real interfaces. They're just lies that the kernel tells to old out-of-date tools such as 'ifconfig', but in reality you just have a single 'eth0' interface with two addresses.